# Why can I change members of a const T& argument

Tags: c++, reference, constants

If a function takes a `const &` argument it should be immutable.
Why can I change values in a `class` passed as `const`?
How can I prevent a function taking `const &` to change values?
Note: compiles on vs2012 ad g++ 4.8.2

```
#include "iostream"

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : a(-99) {}
    int a;
};

class Bar{
public:
    Bar (Foo& f): rFoo(f), pFoo(&f), foo(f) {}
    Foo& rFoo;
    Foo* pFoo;
    Foo  foo;
};

void setA (const Bar &  b){
    Foo* f = new Foo();
    Foo f2 = *f;
    f->a = 7;
    //b.foo.a = 8; // error C3490: 'a' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object
    //b.pFoo = f;  // error C3490: 'pFoo' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object
    b.pFoo->a = 9;   // OK... the pointer is const the location its pointing to not... 
    b.rFoo.a = 10;   // Maybe ... the reference may be const, the location its is referencing not ...
    b.rFoo = *f;     // Why can I modify the reference ?
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Foo f;
    Bar b(f);

    std::cout << "one:   " << b.rFoo.a << std::endl;
    b.pFoo->a = 1;
    b.foo.a = 2;
    std::cout << "two:   " << b.rFoo.a << std::endl;
    setA(b);
    std::cout << "three: " << b.rFoo.a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b.rFoo = *f
```

is not changing rFoo itself, it is equivalent to

```
b.rFoo.operator=(*f);
```

which copies *f to the object referenced by rFoo.

Comment: OK, This means I can call any non const member function on b.rFoo even if b is const (as long as rFoo is not a const&)?
Why is const not propagated to it's members?

Comment: @user3628220: The "const Bar &b" means you cannot modify parts of b. The pointer pFoo and the reference rFoo are part of b and you cannot modify them. The object that pFoo points to and the object that rFoo references are not part of b, they are just referenced/pointed to. So these are not const.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the reference for the same reason you can modify the pointed to object by `pFoo`. Since you aren't modifying the objects member, but another referenced object.

```
b.rFoo = *f; // Foo's assignment operator invoked
```

That's why you should not expose members variables. Since you can't enforce a prevention to modify referenced objects, other than in your own member functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` qualifier of an object indicates that the abstract state of this object won't change (i.e., from the client's point of view). This is not exactly the same as saying that the object's raw bits are not going to change.

It is forbitten to C++ compilers to consider objects as raw bits, unless they can resolve the problem of aliasing. which in your case the compiler cannot. This is due to the fact that `Foo* pFoo` is a pointer to an object and consequently the state of this object is modifiable. That is, even if the object that `pFoo` points to changes, the object that contains `pFoo` (i.e., `b`) doesn't change since `pFoo` continues to point to the same object.